# Execute docker commands from java/jsp/html page

Tags: java, docker

I have to run commands to start docker container from the `jsp` page. when user enters his credentials on login page, I have to start `mysql` container and other containers too.How can we achieve this?

Suggest a solution to trigger/run a docker command from the `java/jsp/html` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker has a [Remote API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/) and maintains a [list of client libraries](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/remote_api_client_libraries/).

Java libraries

- [docker-java](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java)
- [docker-client](https://github.com/spotify/docker-client)
- [jclouds-docker](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-labs/tree/master/docker)

Comment: is it not possible without using remote api?..can you provide simple java/jsp program example how to achieve this using remote api?